# android studio cannot resolve method

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I just migrate to android studio from eclipse. I try one sample project just not working. I cannot figure it out. I hope someone can help me.
I try to call sample class from my main activity. It seems like I cannot call the method from the sample.

```
package com.example.lzp93_000.sample;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.*;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private sample s=new sample();
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    String y=sample.sampleMehod();  // <--- It's not working.
                           //It shows Cannot resolve Method.
}
}



package com.example.lzp93_000.sample;

public class sample {

public String sampleMethod()
{
    String x="100";
    return x;
}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you've not declared `sampleMethod` as `static`, it is an instance member, which means you need to call that method on an instantiated object, not the class itself.

If you want the method to be a static member of the class, simply declare it as such, and the rest of your code is fine:

```
public static String sampleMethod()
```

Otherwise, instantiate a `sample` object, and call the method on that:

```
sample s = new sample();
String y = s.sampleMethod();
```

You have the method name misspelled in the code you've posted, by the way.

Additionally, following standard Java naming convention, the `sample` class name should be capitalized - `Sample`.